# sed -- replace variable in for do loop

Tags: bash, sed

I want to insert a counter into a text file using sed. For example, the file has the following content:

```
please.add.number.00
```

Here is the script I'm using:

```
for i in $(seq 0 10)
do
sed -i 's/please.add.number.00/please.add.number.$i/' filename.txt
done
```

But the value (`$i`) in the file doesn't change. I want to substitute the value of $i in this line of filename.txt. I would appreciate any help to fix this issue!

Comment: Variables don't expand in single quotes. Use double quotes.

Comment: Are you sure you want `seq 10 10`  ?

Comment: `$(seq 10 10)` just produces `10` so there's no looping. If there *was* a loop (say 'seq 10 20'), this would replace all `...number.00` with `...number.10` and no more replacements would take place, because there would be no more '...number.00' left after doing the first replacement. Also note that the dots in `please.add.number.00` are *wildcards* while those in `please.add.number.$i` are literal *periods.*

Comment: sorry there was a typo in the for loop; it should be for i in $(seq 0 10)

Comment: the goal is to change the value from 1 to 50 in this line ..i thought sed would do it..and double quote in sed .."...." did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, [there is a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) between these two lines:

```
echo '$HOME'
echo "$HOME"
```

Single quotes will result in `$HOME`, double quotes will tell you your home directory.

Based on edits to your question, it looks like your actual problem is a case of misunderstanding how `sed` works. The [substitute command](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-1) takes two parameters: a search pattern and a replacement. If the search pattern (`please.add.number.00`) never changes, then it will only ever be matched the first time it is run.